# How can I create an Elytra booster?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to replicate the spider queens bone in logdotzip's ccmp series. I've gotten pretty far, however I can't finish it. I've gotten up to

```
/execute ~0 ~0.1 ~0 [player] summon spider and /testfor item.weapon.offhand minecraft:bone
```

The things I need help with is combining both commands, getting the order of the string of commands right, getting the name of the bone to have to be "Spider Queen's Bone", having no drops come from the spiders, and killing only the spiders spawned by the bone. There may be missing things because I am new to larger commands.

Comment: @rivermont Please, when you edit, don't only edit the tags. Such an edit is likely to get rejected and also, there is *much* more to improve in such a post. Please improve as much as you can when editing. Thanks!

Comment: summon the spider with a name so that only the spiders with that name will be killed

Answer (score 1):

Well I have been working on something similar and I found that for testing for named armor this works:
`{Inventory:[{Slot:-101b*,tag:{display:{Name:"cat"}}}]}`
 but I am working on something that would go in your leggings slot called rocket boosters but would work the same way except with invisible silverfish. If you have any further questions about that I would suggest asking the minecraft forum user and moderator Skylinerw [here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/members/Skylinerw).

For your other question I found [this link](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/2085128-summon-mob-with-0-drop-chance)
which states that having no string or eyes drop is impossible but I know it is possible to use custom loot tables in some way, you might have to have a renamed spider but that is easy.

*As in helmet slot, also don't include the "*" in the command.

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer all your questions but here goes:I have no idea how you would combine them also...

But I do know the link to Logdotzip's CCMP world + all the modules used:
http://www.mediafire.com/download/jw77tr3xn2rvrjx/
The link to Jragon's site where he originally posted the 1.8+1.9 spider queen's bone module (More Creatures): http://jragoncommands.weebly.com/jragon-modpack-instructions.html

So you would have to update it and compile it but I have a feeling that you should start doing it directly in 1.11 because 1.11 changed mob ids

Comment: If you want to chain mulitple command blocks to execute the commands try a fill clock. If you don't know what a fill clock is, google it.